# Determine the largest positive $k$ such that $e^{|x|}-|x|+\cos x \geq k$

Tags: analysis, functions, solution-verification

Determine the largest positive integer $k$ such that $e^{|x|}-|x|+\cos x \geq k$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt: let $f_k(x)=e^{|x|}-|x|+\cos x-k$, the inequality is then equivalent to find the largest positive integer $k$ such that $f_k(x) \geq 0$.

Since $f_k(x)=f_k(-x)$, it follows that $f$ is even and so, by symmetry, I can study it for $x \geq 0$; so, for $x \geq 0$, it is $f_k(x) =e^x-x+\cos x -k$.

It is $f_k'(x)=e^x-1-\sin x$, and from the inequalities $e^x \geq 1+x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x \geq \sin x$ for all $x \geq 0$, it is $f_k'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.

I notice that $f_k(0)=2-k$, so if $k \in \{1,2\}$ it is $f_k(0) \geq 0$ and so, by monotonicity, for $k\in\{1,2\}$ it is $f_k(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$ and so for these values the inequality holds.

If $k\geq3$ the inequality can't hold for all $x\geq0$, since $f_k$ is continuous, it is $f_k \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f_k(0)<0$, so for the intermediate value theorem there exists $\tilde{x} \in [0,\infty)$ such that $f_k(x) <0$ for $x\in[0,\tilde{x}]$.

Is my work correct? Thanks to anyone who will correct me or give me a confirmation. Any other approach is welcome.

Comment: If $x\geq 0$ then you should have had $e^{-x}$ at the beginning.

Comment: @NinadMunshi: You're right, it was a typo. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Do you mean "for all real $x$"? Or for a certain $x$?

Comment: @user: I meant for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, I've edited accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Your work is correct, but you did not give the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

As you say, we need only consider $x\ge 0$. So let $f(x)=e^x-x+\cos x$. You correctly state that $f'(x)\ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$.

Therefore $f(x)\ge f(0)=2$ for all $x\ge 0$. Hence $k=2$.